# Sometimes getting wrong time using localtime() function

Tags: c, time

I want to display time of the current day after every 300 seconds. I am using localtime function. Most of the time ,it show right value but sometime it gives totally different value than expected one.

eg. At time HH:MM:SS i.e. 17:05:46 i get value as 81346 which is right one but at time 17:07:41 expected value is 81461 but I get value as 66052. Why is it so ?

```
   #include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(void)
{
        time_t curtime ;
        struct tm *loctime ;
        int cur_time = 0;
        unsigned int counter=0;
        while(1)
        {
                if(!(counter %300))
                {
                        curtime = time(NULL)+ 19800;
                        loctime = localtime ( &curtime )  ;

                        cur_time = (loctime->tm_hour*3600)+(loctime->tm_min*60)+loctime->tm_sec;
                        printf("Cur_time= %d \r\n",cur_time);
                }
                sleep(1);
                counter++;
                printf("counter= %d \r\n",counter);
        }

        return 1;
}
```

Comment: It seems strange that you are applying your own 5½ hour time difference, and it isn't clear where you are getting `81346` etc from. It's not the value of `time()` nor of `counter`, and `17:05:46` is `61546` seconds into the day.

Comment: `if(!(counter %300))` `counter++;`, like, can't you just `counter += 300`? `Why is it so ?` Please display the full data and full hour when the difference shows. Could it be daylight saving time adjustment?

Comment: Note that calling `sleep(1)` 300 times isn't going to take exactly 300 seconds (even without any other operations). It would be more reliable to check the value from `time` itself, and you'll get an exact 5:00 minutes too.

Comment: @WeatherVane I want to get IST (Indian Standard Time) .so thats why I added 5.30 hours

Comment: `printf("Cur_time= %d \r\n", (int)cur_time);` ?? (and `printf("counter= %u \r\n",counter);`)

Comment: Isn't that the point of `localtime()`?

Comment: @KamilCuk I though that it is hapening at dayswitching time. but it happens randomly. after next 300 seconds  ,it print right time

Comment: @WeatherVane 1.is there need to reset the value of cur_time with 0 in while loop. so that it will not take garbage value
2.is there need to reset the value of loctime->tm_isdst =-1 before each call in while loop??

Comment: I misread your use of two almost-identical variable names `curtime` and  `cur_time`. Please read [`localtime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/localtime-localtime32-localtime64?view=msvc-160) page. You don't need to set `curtime` to `0` if you are immediately going to set it to another value.